# Save text in input to cookies and display it to user everytime he visits it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I need help with saving the input to cookies and displaying it to the user. I need to make the text in the input to change into the div and display the same text for the user every time he visits the page.

Now I have just the input because I really don't know how to make it.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="name" placeholder="What's your name?"/>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:700');
.name{
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3.5vw;
    border: 0;
    outline:0;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    width: 30%;
    color:#000000;
    position:fixed;
    top:60%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Thanks for your the help

Comment: Do you want the cookies to be generated by the server or by the webpage?

Comment: For the server one, will I need a database?

Comment: I think by the webpage.

Comment: No.You do not need a database. You can just generate cookies using PHP

Comment: I don't know. What is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend setting the cookie with your backend (e.g PHP). 
However, if you want to only use client-side implementation, you can use **js.cookie** library.

Here is a simple working code that uses Cookies written and read by javascript only. It listens to the keydown event, so that every letter typed into the input automatically updates the cookie.

**Important**: Make sure you use a webserver when running it (for example: http://localhost/index.html and not file://c:/index.html. Otherwise cookies won't work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.1.3/js.cookie.js"></script>
<body>
    <input id="name" type="text" class="name" placeholder="What's your name?"/>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var name = Cookies.get('_username');
            if (name) {
                $('#name').val(name);
            }
            $('#name').keydown(function(){
                var inputName = $('#name').val();
                Cookies.set('_username', inputName);
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```