# How to save text within a textarea to localstorage

Tags: javascript

I need to save text within an textarea with localStorage.

Here is the HTML code:

```css
.textarea {
  background: none;
  color: lime;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  border: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="textarea" id="notes" value="Type something!">
Delete this and start typing!</textarea>
```

How can I save the text locally? Searches did not get me anywhere.

Comment: Why a cookie and not local storage? This problem doesn't seem like it needs to be using cookies.

Comment: By local storage do you mean file?

Comment: No, I mean [local storage](https://medium.com/@krishankantsinghal/local-storage-vs-session-storage-vs-cookie-22655ff75a8) ||| [Here too](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Ok, can you show me what it would look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Comment: `"Ok, can you show me what it would look like?"` I did, @LegitCoder, look at the second link that i sent in the previous message

Comment: Ok, so I have 

```function saveLocal(){var text = document.getElementById("notes").value;
  localStorage.setItem('text', text);
}```

How do I retrieve it on a load and put it inside the textare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like localStorage is a better option for your use case.

That said, you can get your textarea value with:

```
document.getElementById("notes").value
```

After that, as you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4825695/5827913), you can use

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

So to summarize, you can create your cookie with something like the following:

```
let value = document.getElementById("notes").value;
createCookie('textareaValue', value, 0);
```

## UPDATE

Since you updated your question to only use localStorage, you can use this:

```
let value = document.getElementById("notes").value;
localStorage.setItem("textareaValue", value);
```

You can retrieve and display the value with:

```
let value = localStorage.getItem('textareaValue');
document.getElementById("notes").value = value;
```

Comment: I changed my question. I want to use localStorage now

Comment: @LegitCoder makes sense, please check if the updated part of the answer works for you

Comment: Okay, how do I display the localStorage in the same textarea?

Comment: @LegitCoder I just added that too

Comment: Okay, thanks so much! 

EDIT: Really sorry, but can you add a code snippet so I can see an example?

Comment: Really sorry, but can you add a code snippet so I can see an example?

Comment: Nvm. Thanks again!

Comment: @LegitCoder happy to help! Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you just want to modify `document.cookie` by hand:

```js
document.cookie = "mytext=stuff"
// this will add "mytext" key to page cookies and assign "stuff"

document.cookie = "mytext=newstuff"
// this will modify your key, cookies works just like associative array

document.cookies = "mytext=;max-age=0"
// this will delete your cookie by setting its max age to 0, so cookie is being considered expired now
```

Stack Overflow has a nice thread on this topic: [How to get and set cookies in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312980/how-to-get-and-set-cookies-in-javascript/51313011).

In order to grab the text from your `<textarea>` you might want to use `my_html_element.value`, where `my_html_element` is HTML node.

Also the following syntax might be useful:

```js
let variable = "some text";
`string${variable}` // stringsome text
```

Comment: Thanks, but Im planning to use locaStorage

Comment: @LegitCoder consider changing your answer then :)

Comment: Do you mean "question" @PaulLynn?

Comment: @Samathingamajig oh, yes. Sorry, it's 2 AM at my location.

Comment: Wait, @PaulLynn do you know how to save it locally?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Javascript with your html, here is already something that is available on stack overflow:

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41575221/save-text-in-input-to-cookies-and-display-it-to-user-everytime-he-visits-it)